# Run-time dynamic linking one class within another

Tags: vb.net

I have two classes, one called Caller and another called Responder. The Caller assembly needs to run-time dynamic link Responder and use one of its methods. I also need to be able to unload the Responder assembly when this is done.

For some reason I can't explain, I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Responder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Responder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at Caller.Caller.Testing() in *\Caller.vb:line 4
```

I don't rightly know how the file is resolved, but I've checked through properties on an object created through `System.Reflection.Assembly`, to confirm the `Assembly.FullName` and `Type.FullName`. The files are also both located in the same directory.

For context, I'm working with iLogic (Autodesk Inventor). I've created a class library that is referenced within event trigger rules. When any application instance is open, it's impossible for me to push changes to the .dll's. I figure if I can get this run-time dynamic linking working, it might allow me to make changes to these files without needing to have all my coworkers shut down any open applications that have referenced them at any point. That said, I'm open to alternatives to this strategy.

Caller class:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Caller
    Shared Sub Testing()
        Dim oDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain")
        Dim oObj As Object = oDomain.CreateInstance("Responder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "Responder.Responder")
        oObj.Testing()
        AppDomain.Unload(oDomain)
    End Sub
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And Responder class:

```
Public Class Responder
    Public Sub Testing()
        MsgBox("hello")
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for reading this far
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to change the build order so that responder is created before caller can used and call it

Comment: no luck but good thought. I have the dependency explicitly set now in Visual Studio